# Server 2012R2 shuts down every Sunday morning

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Since the installation of the July Microsoft updates, my server shuts down at 00:58 every Sunday morning, every week. Then fails to restart, stuck at the blue screen Kernel_Data_Inpage_Error.

The server had been working fine for months before July. I've looked through the Task Scheduler and the only task that runs at 1am is the Maintenance Configurator task, but that runs every day. So if that were the problem I'd expect the server to stop every day at about 1am.

The server only runs one application, which this week I scheduled to stop at 00:45, however, the server still stopped, but at 01:08.

I've run memtest86 from a boot CD for 3 hours and found no memory problems. The C drive is new, but I ran `chkdsk /scan` anyway and no errors were found.

I've installed the August updates, but that didn't change the situation.
I'd appreciate any thoughts or ideas please.

Answer (score 2):

1. It can be a virus or even bad blocks in his new hard drive. Test not the file system but the disk itself using any testing tool like Victoria HDD, etc. The issue can be caused by the bad block in page file of Windows (which is by default located on C: drive). I would also suggest to check and set the pagefile size to 4096, check the applications for scheduled tasks.
2. the issue can be related to the non-paged pool after the updates. The non-paged pool can grow very fast and then BSOD. Check and update the server firmware (Network drivers can be an issue). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms854944.aspx

Comment: Apologies for the delay in my reply. I had to make each change suggested one at a time & then wait until the next Sunday to see if the server failed. I did try stopping the Internet time sync & advancing the clock to 0055 on a Sunday, but the server just carried on working. I reset the clock & sure enough it failed the next Sunday. The last change I've made is the pagefile size. It was greater than 4096. I set it to 4096 3 weeks ago & for the past 3 Sundays, the server has stayed up. Looks like this was the issue, hope I haven't spoken too soon. Thanks very much for your detailed suggestions.